# Resize logo image

Tags: html, css, image, resize

So I have a probably really dumb question but I'm very new to coding.

I want to be able to resize and center my logo image (which is currently taking up the whole page on preview) but I've tried so many different ways of resizing in CSS and nothing at all happens. What am I missing??

Besides the standard beginning of HTML file this is all I have in my HTML file:

```
<div class="header">
<img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="\Stuff logo">
</div>
```

These are the only lines I have in my CSS file:

```
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
  max-width: 20%;
  max-height: 20%;
}
```

Comment: if you want your logo image at the center so give `display: block` and `margin: auto` to your image. and for resizing give width.

Answer (score 0):

```css
img{
     display:block;
     margin:0 auto;
     width:10%;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1575881875475-31023242e3f9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8Mnx8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
  
     
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just tried it, nothing is happening, its still huge taking up the whole page. Is is because it's an image from the directory? I just don't understand why it's not changing

Comment: no, it's not like that, can you provide me the img to me?  or give me the link of the image you have downloaded.

Comment: Its a png included for an assignment, I'm not sure how to upload the image on here